# Are there any exceptions to Java package naming for international users?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

While I understand the principle of the reversed URL system, it only seems to make sense for companies with non-national domains. While the package name beginning with com. or org. is useful and brief and gives a suggestion as to the likely license, the idea that a package must begin with uk. , fr. , jp. etc - and then usually another part for that country's version of .com or .org - simply because of where it was written, which is irrelevant to its use in software, seems silly.

Is there any standard alternate convention for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While the package name beginning with com. or org. is useful

IMHO it is only useful if your code is going to be shared with another company or organisation.

In most projects, companies go to great lengths to ensure their IP stays in the company. So it doesn't make sense to use a structure designed for sharing code. BTW even if the project is required to change later, this isn't a problem and you can change the package of a JAR with a tools like jarjar.

So not useful for most intra company projects.

> Is there any standard alternate convention for this?

I would name the package after the name of the module. e.g. if you are using maven I would use

```
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
```

and make the package match

```
package mygroupid.myartifactid;
```

or a sub package.

This works whether you use a domain name or not.